# ERC223, drawbacks and exchanges still not supporting it? Should I just use HasNoTokens?

Tags: tokens, erc-20, exchanges, erc-223

I know it has been discussed many times and in many [articles](https://medium.com/cryptomover/what-are-erc20-and-erc223-tokens-307badcca5a) on [ERC223](https://delegatecall.com/questions/ERC223), for replacing [ERC20](https://delegatecall.com/questions/ERC20).

We are launching our tokens and hopefully ICO soon too, it seems that we should go for ERC223, since more and more developers adopting it. Before we go further, I would like to know more practical drawbacks and any exchanges that still not supporting it? Any existing popular token using ERC223?

AFAIK, implementing Openzeppelin's [HasNoTokens](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/ownership/HasNoTokens.sol) should (kind of) fix the lost token problem. Is that good enough?